Can the PhraseListGrammar be used with the IntentRecognizer in the Microsoft Speech SDK for Java?
I have a Java app that is doing speech recognition using the Speech SDK for Microsoft's Azure Speech Service. I am attempting to apply a phrase list onto an IntentRecognizer using the PhraseListGrammar class to improve recognition for names (e.g. "Jun", "Rehaan") but I am seeing no improvement for the name recognition. However, when I swap the IntentRecognizer for a SpeechRecognizer then the speech service is able to recognize the names in the given speech audio, just fine.
The code example for phrase lists from Microsoft is only done with the SpeechRecognizer (example)
    AudioConfig audioInput = AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput("YourPhraseListedAudioFile.wav");
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput);
        {
            // Create the recognizer.
            PhraseListGrammar phraseList = PhraseListGrammar.fromRecognizer(recognizer);

            // Add a phrase to assist in recognition.
            phraseList.addPhrase("Wreck a nice beach");

            // Subscribes to events.
            recognizer.recognizing.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
                System.out.println("RECOGNIZING: Text=" + e.getResult().getText());
            });

            recognizer.recognized.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
                if (e.getResult().getReason() == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                    System.out.println("RECOGNIZED: Text=" + e.getResult().getText());
                }
                else if (e.getResult().getReason() == ResultReason.NoMatch) {
                    System.out.println("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                }
            });

            recognizer.canceled.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
                System.out.println("CANCELED: Reason=" + e.getReason());

                if (e.getReason() == CancellationReason.Error) {
                    System.out.println("CANCELED: ErrorCode=" + e.getErrorCode());
                    System.out.println("CANCELED: ErrorDetails=" + e.getErrorDetails());
                    System.out.println("CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                }

                stopRecognitionSemaphore.release();
            });

            recognizer.sessionStarted.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
                System.out.println("\n    Session started event.");
            });

and I am essentially following this example. Is it not possible to use phrase lists with the IntentRecognizer using the PhraseListGrammar class? If not, is there another way to apply phrase lists onto the IntentRecognizer?


Is it not possible to use phrase lists with the IntentRecognizer using the PhraseListGrammar class?

Unfortunately, directly applying a phrase list onto the IntentRecognizer using the PhraseListGrammar class is not supported in the Microsoft Speech SDK for Java.

The IntentRecognizer in the Speech SDK for Java is primarily designed for language understanding tasks, where you define intents and entities to extract meaning from the user's input. It doesn't have built-in support for specifying custom phrase lists like the SpeechRecognizer does.

I had work around with this limitation by using a combination of the SpeechRecognizer and the PhraseListGrammar.
Code:
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your Speech Service configuration (subscription key, region, etc.)
        SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");

        // Load audio from a WAV file (replace with your actual file path)
        AudioConfig audioInput = AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput("YourPhraseListedAudioFile.wav");

        // Create a SpeechRecognizer
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput);

        // Create a PhraseListGrammar
        PhraseListGrammar phraseList = PhraseListGrammar.fromRecognizer(recognizer);
        phraseList.addPhrase("Jun");
        phraseList.addPhrase("Rehaan");

        // Subscribe to recognizing and recognized events
        recognizer.recognizing.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
            System.out.println("RECOGNIZING: Text=" + e.getResult().getText());
        });

        recognizer.recognized.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
            if (e.getResult().getReason() == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                System.out.println("RECOGNIZED: Text=" + e.getResult().getText());
            } else if (e.getResult().getReason() == ResultReason.NoMatch) {
                System.out.println("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
            }
        });

        // Start recognition
        recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();

        // Wait for recognition to complete (you can use a semaphore or other synchronization mechanism)
        Semaphore stopRecognitionSemaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        recognizer.canceled.addEventListener((s, e) -> {
            System.out.println("CANCELED: Reason=" + e.getReason());
            if (e.getReason() == CancellationReason.Error) {
                System.out.println("CANCELED: ErrorCode=" + e.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("CANCELED: ErrorDetails=" + e.getErrorDetails());
                System.out.println("CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
            }
            stopRecognitionSemaphore.release();
        });

        // Wait for recognition to finish (you can adjust the timeout as needed)
        try {
            stopRecognitionSemaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Clean up resources
        recognizer.close();
    }
}

IntentRecognizer vs SpeechRecognizer:

The  IntentRecognizer  is typically used for natural language understanding (NLU) tasks, where you define intents and entities to extract structured information from spoken language.
The  SpeechRecognizer, on the other hand, is more focused on transcribing spoken audio into text without specific intent recognition.
It’s possible that the  IntentRecognizer  may not fully utilize the phrase list hints provided by the  PhraseListGrammar.

Refer:

Intent recognition quickstart - Speech service - Azure AI services


I see, I will experiment with the SpeechRecognizer or combining the two recognizers in that case. Thank you!
